# why is my gloval setInterval ID variable unavailable to a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I am writing a simple timer app and using setInterval for the first time. The project is in react typescript and I use the useReducer hook to manage state.

The project requires two separate timers, session and break, which may explain some of the code. The project also requires one button to start and stop the timer, hence I am using a single function.

I have redacted my reducer and types as the problem, as i understand, does not involve them, but some simple use of setInterval that I just don't get yet.

When the startStopTimer function is called a second time, the intervalID is undefined, even though it is declared globally.

```
const App = () => {
    const [timerState, dispatch] = useReducer(timerStateReducer, initialTimerState
    );

    let intervalID: NodeJS.Timer;

    const startStopTimer = () => {
        let name: string = timerState.session.count !== 0 ? 'session' : 'break';
        
        if (timerState[name].running) {
            console.log('stopping timer' + intervalID);
            //reducer sets running boolean variable to false
            dispatch({type: ActionKind.Stop, name: name});
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        } else {
           //reducer sets running boolean variable to true
            dispatch({type: ActionKind.Start, name: name}); 
            intervalID = setInterval(() => {
                dispatch({type: ActionKind.Decrease, name: name});
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

return (
      //redacted JSX code
       <button onClick={startStopTimer}>Start/Stop</button>
)
```

I have tried passing onClick as an arrow function (rather than a reference, i think?) and it behaves the same. I tried simplifying this with useState, but came across a whole 'nother set of issues with useState and setInterval so I went back to the useReducer hook.

Thanks!

Comment: Defined "globally" doesn't mean its value isn't getting reset when App re-renders? Try putting it in state, or use useRef for it.

Comment: bingo. useState hook did the trick. thanks!